# Isomorphism between the group of upper triangular matrix in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $(‎\mathbb{Z}_{3}‎\times\mathbb{Z}_{3})‎\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Tags: group-theory

By a‎ ‎well ‎known ‎fact ‎we ‎have: ‎
‎
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)‎‎\vert‎‎‎a,b,c\in‎\mathbb{F}_{3}\right\} ‎‎\cong(‎\mathbb{Z}_{3}‎\times\mathbb{Z}_{3})‎\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{3}
\end{equation}
‎
Now I have two questions:‎‎

1) What is the action of ‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{Z}_3‎‎$‎ on ‎$‎\mathbb{Z}_3 ‎\times \mathbb{Z}_3‎‎$‎?‎‎

2) Under which isomorphism these two groups are isomorphic?‎

Many thanks.

Comment: Tried to fix your TeX code.
Does this looks good?
$$\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)‎‎\vert‎‎‎a,b,c\in‎\mathbb{F}_{3}\right\} ‎‎\cong(‎\mathbb{Z}_{3}‎\times\mathbb{Z}_{3})‎\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{3}$$

Comment: Yes of course! That's right. many thanks Ilmārs Cīrulis! I tried so much to write this but I couldn't.

Comment: How is it that the fact is well-known and you are asking these questions?! :-)

Comment: It's nice. :)
But I messed little bit up lines (= lost few linebreaks) and can't fix it because such change is too small to be allowed.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez! actually I think it is well-known, because I saw it in an article without any detail. Maybe it isn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take for $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ the normal subgroup
$$
\left\{
\alpha_{a,b}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
  & 1 & \\
&&1
\end{bmatrix}
:
a, b \in \mathbb{F}_{3}
\right\},
$$
(I am omitting zeroes) and for the "other" $\mathbb{Z}_3$ the subgroup
$$
\left\{
\gamma_{c} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  & \\
  & 1 & c \\
&&1
\end{bmatrix}
:
c \in \mathbb{F}_{3}
\right\}.
$$
It is easly checked that the action is given by
$$
\gamma_{c}^{-1} \alpha_{a,b} \gamma_{c} = \alpha_{a, ac+b}.
$$
This should tell you everything you want.

Comment: Dear Andreas Caranti thank you!

Comment: @shankfei, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Write the matrix in your question as $(a,b,c)$ for simplicity and —computing explicitly— find the formula for the product $(a,b,c)\cdot(a',b',c')$ This should make it obvious how the semi-direct product is constructed.